# Display HTML Calculated Percentage % From Static Number

Tags: javascript, calculation

I can calculate and google (I have) etc, am a glorified designer, but just need this vanilla inline JS to calculate and display %

The title says it all. Basically, I want to calculate 15% of static number (which is display dynamically by WooCommerce) and display below or somewhere whatever by the original bummer :)

EDITED:

HTML Rendered:

```
<p class="price">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">R</span> 102.00
</span>
</p>
```

Would like to display:

```
<p class="price">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">R</span>
102.00</span>
Club Price: (102 - 15% = just the 86 or 87) 86.7
</p>
```

Here's demo link, see R 102 http://siliconvineyards.co.za/wine-shop/glen-carlou-cabernet-sauvignon-2015/

Comment: Do you have any markup to show that someone could apply this inline js to? Is it displayed in an input? Is it dynamic? Does it need an onChange listener? etc...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while SO is here to help with code you wrote, SO is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 100;
var discount = .15 * num;
```

Comment: So the part of I can do math went missing... :p

Comment: Soz, that was a little more informational than what I thought... I realise the problem is more complicated than what I thought.... in terms of ID and numerical & characters... etc, ugh